# Change property name of as_json call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with the following method:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord:Base
  def as_json(options = nil)
    if options.nil?
      super(only: [:id, :title, :status, :description])
    else
      super(options)
    end
  end
end
```

I also have a controller that looks like:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
  def search
    books = Book.where(title: params[:keyword])

    render json: books.as_json(only: [:id, :title])
  end
end
```

Is it possible to override the :title symbol with another name that is needed by a 3rd party application?  I'd like to change the :title to :value just for pushing out via this JSON call.

I've tried doing several different things to override (without writing special rules in as_json, as this is called from serveral different locations in the application).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the "value" attribute in your model? Maybe you can create method *def value; title; end* and use it in options...

Comment: No, there is not a "value" property. I'm needing to change the :title to :value temporarily just for this render in the JSON that is returned.

Answer (score 3):

So, this the solution I ended up using:

JSON before .tap call:

```
[{"id"=>4, "book_code"=>"11-292454", "title"=>"How the world turns."}]
```

For single JSON object:

```
json = json.tap { |hash| hash["value"] = hash.delete "title" }
```

For JSON array:

```
json = json.each do |j|
  j.tap { |hash| hash["value"] = hash.delete "title" }
end
```

JSON after .tap call:

```
[{"id"=>4, "book_code"=>"11-292454", "value"=>"How the world turns."}]
```

Don't know if it's the right way, but it seems to be working for me.